# Склейка строк в двух вариантах

Tags: delphi

**Первый файл** имеет строки такого вида:

```
№1-Price_a
№2-Price_b
№3-Price_c
```

**Второй файл** имеет строки такого вида:

```
01.12.2018
02.12.2018
03.12.2018
```

**Задание:**

Вариант первый (**На выходе - результат**):

```
№1-Price_a;01.12.2018
№1-Price_a;02.12.2018
№1-Price_a;03.12.2018
№2-Price_b;01.12.2018
№2-Price_b;02.12.2018
№2-Price_b;03.12.2018
№3-Price_c;01.12.2018
№3-Price_c;02.12.2018
№3-Price_c;03.12.2018
```

Вариант второй (**На выходе - результат**):

```
№1-Price_a;01.12.2018
№2-Price_b;01.12.2018
№3-Price_c;01.12.2018
№1-Price_a;02.12.2018
№2-Price_b;02.12.2018
№3-Price_c;02.12.2018
№1-Price_a;03.12.2018
№2-Price_b;03.12.2018
№3-Price_c;03.12.2018
```

Как склеить просто я то понимаю. 
**Когда делаю вот так:**

Где

```
S- Это строки из первого файла
S2 - Это строки из второго файла
```

**Когда пишу код вот так:**

```
s := s + ';' + s2;
```

**То получаю результат только вот такой:**

```
№1-Price_a:01.12.2018
№2-Price_b:02.12.2018
№3-Price_c:03.12.2018
```

**Помогите осилить задачу...**

Comment: Напишите цикл в цикле.

Comment: @Igor, Вот тут я еще не силен... Даже не знаю как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure multiplyStrings(src1, src2, dst: TStrings);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  dst.Clear;
  for i := 0 to src1.Count - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to src2.Count - 1 do
    begin
      dst.Add(src1[i] + ';' + src2[j]);
    end;
  end;
end;


var 
  lines1, lines2, destination: TStringList;
begin
  lines1 := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lines2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
      lines1.LoadFromFile('первый файл');
      lines2.LoadFromFile('второй файл');

      destination := TStringList.Create;
      try
        // Вариант первый 
        multiplyStrings(lines1, lines2, destination);
        // Вариант второй
        multiplyStrings(lines2, lines1, destination);

        destination.SaveToFile('новый файл');
      finally
        destination.Fre;
      end;
    finally
      lines2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lines1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Все, разобрался,а то я немножко затормозил... Личная благодарность.

Comment: Если Вам не сложно можете подсказать как функцию переделать под построчное чтение  Readln и Writeln. А то опыта маловато, благодарю.

Comment: @Денис Мне лестно, что Вы так в меня верите ), но для этого мне надо знать, что эти `Readln`/`Writeln` должны делать. А лучше задать отдельный вопрос с ясно поставленной задачей.

Comment: А тут, я немного прочитал :). Ну смотрите, тут просто, такая ситуация что у меня файлы не маленький а оперативной памяти всего 1 гигабайт и вашим кодом я гружу все в память. А хотелось бы вариант с чтением построчно, я то понимаю что скорость будет меньше но за то оперативная память не будет нагружаться... Учу Delphi только 1 месяц...

Comment: Igor, Помогите сделать тоже самое только с построчным чтением Readln/Writeln....

Comment: Создал новую тему по этому вопросу: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916986/Построчное-чтение-readln-writeln

Answer (score 0):

Я бы просто сделал вот так и это было бы правильно

```
Var
i,j:Integer;
```

И цикл

```
for i:= 0 to Length ( S ) do
for j:= 0 to Length ( S2 ) do
s[i] := s[i] + r1 + s2[j];
```

Comment: Неправильное оформление кода это я Вам точно скажу, хотя я новенький в этом деле...

Comment: @Igor, Мой вариант стабильней вашего.

Comment: Не говорите глупостей user318687 и ставлю Вам минус за Ваши не знания. Код у Igor нормально работает.

Comment: @user318687 Возможно. Все зависит от того, что мы понимаем под "стабильностью" ).

Comment: @Igor, правильно сказано. Как минимум ошибка у пользователя user318687 уже вот где :) s[i] := s[i] + r1 + s2[j]; Рассуждаю выходя из своего опыта.